# Arbitrary number of function overloads

Tags: typescript

I'm using the following code to overload a function defining an 'event' handler.

```js
export function on(eventName: 'created', eventCallback: (args: { uuid: string }) => void): any;
export function on(eventName: 'updated', eventCallback: (args: { id: number }) => void): any;
export function on(eventName: any, eventCallback: any) {

}
```

Is there any way I can template this process so that I can overload this function with an abitruary number of events:

```js
type Events = ['created',{uuid: string}] | ['updated',{id: number}];

export function on(eventName: any, eventCallback: any) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a union of tuples into an intersection of function signatures via something like [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) and that would be a direct analog of overloads.

However in this case I'd be inclined to use the union of tuples directly as a [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) of a single function signature:

```
type Events = ['created', { uuid: string }] | ['updated', { id: number }];

export function on(...[eventName, eventCallback]: Events) {

}

on('created', { uuid: "" }); // okay
on('updated', { id: 1 }); // okay
on('created', { id: 1 }); // error
```

Maybe that would work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA2gcgMYBOEAhsBACY4A0UA3lAK4MCW5AXFCsAc4gOZQAvgF0oAH2w4GYcqQrU6UVh0QMAtgCMIBIcIDcAWABQxiAA8wAewLAoAMwaI8wZpcRQ3ACgB0vrBARkADliNQgaAKRgAGFiABs4jWI8AGthDngolABKOmNjQSh8oy98IjlKGnomZSgAIjqhbL0oAHpWjxTiEGNS6VkySsVagEYmlvbO7t7ETzKSQYV6UfG2ju0CayA)